# Vim/Emacs keybinding for `Preview.app`

Tags: keyboard, pdf, preview, emacs, macvim

Does anybody have ideas about using `emacs`/ `vim` key binding for `Preview.app` to browser `pdf` files and how?

Comment: What exact keybindings are you looking for? To browse PDF files you can already easily use ⌥↑ or ⌥↓, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the "Up" and "Down" keyboard shortcuts by going to System Preferences / Keyboard / Application Shortcuts, add a new shortcut for Preview.app. I've mapped <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to down, <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> to up. It won't let you map just <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>, for some reason. But at least you can now browse a PDF without leaving the home row.

Comment: This is a great tip! If only there was a way to get it to scroll smoothly. I always lose track of where I was when going a full page down.

Comment: @ted "Up" and "Down" do not scroll. I'd like the behavior of the up/down arrow keys. How do you know "Up" and "Down is the exact name of the shortcut you have to put in the preference? Is that listed anywhere? If we have that list, maybe we can find out what the shortcut for "Scroll Up" and "Scroll Down" is.

Answer (score 5):

As @tty suggested, using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) is brilliant. I made some extra rules.

You can navigate using HJKL and zoom using FDER. Read the file for more information.

Here is my `private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>PREVIEW</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Preview</equal>
  </appdef>

  <item>
    <name>Vi Navigation in Preview</name>
    <identifier>private.preview.vinav</identifier>
    <only>PREVIEW</only>
    <uielementrole_not>AXTextField, AXTextArea</uielementrole_not>
    <modifier_only>
        ModifierFlag::NONE,
        ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
        ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    </modifier_only>
    <appendix>Navigate using the HJKL keys</appendix>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
  </item>

  <item>
    <name>Vi Zoom in Preview</name>
    <identifier>private.preview.vizoom</identifier>
    <only>PREVIEW</only>
    <uielementrole_not>AXTextField, AXTextArea</uielementrole_not>
    <modifier_only>
        ModifierFlag::NONE,
        ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
        ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    </modifier_only>
    <appendix>Zoom using E/R: out/in</appendix>
    <appendix>Zoom to fit: F</appendix>
    <appendix>Zoom to 100%: D</appendix>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, KeyCode::KEYPAD_9, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, KeyCode::KEYPAD_0, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::R, KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::E, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: It had worked perfectly, but a few weeks ago it stopped working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No, I'm not using this anymore. I assume you installed an updated version of Karabiner? If you find the solution feel free to edit. Or let me know what to change.

Comment: It turns out that this file is case sensitive so the Preview identifier should be `com.apple.Preview`; not `com.apple.preview`.

Comment: Updating this answer with my latest findings, since there's a newer version of  [karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements). After following the installation steps, I went ahead and installed the system wide vimium shortcut keys profile. This gives me vimium like mechanics throughout the system (MIND BLOW!!!). I removed some slippery slope shortcuts; such as `x` which maps to `cmd-q` and other shortcuts. But the config file is very simple to modify and is located under `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

Very excellent!!!

I found it recently.

https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please also show how the recommended product can actually be used to solve the problem described in the question. The more specific an answer is in regards of the question, the more useful it is for others.

Answer (score 2):

Self-plug – I’ve made a Karabiner rule that adds vim jk bindings to Preview. I didn’t want to use the other Karabiner rules that added systemwide vim bindings.

https://github.com/xrisk/preview-vim

To use: copy the `preview-vim.json` file from the repository (or take the copy from below), paste it in your `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications`, and then enable the rule from Karabiner.

```
{
    "title": "Map jk in Preview",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "map jk",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "j"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "down_arrow"
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "frontmost_application_if",
                            "bundle_identifiers": ["^com.apple.Preview$"]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "k"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "up_arrow"
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "frontmost_application_if",
                            "bundle_identifiers": ["^com.apple.Preview$"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Contributions are welcome!

Also sidenote: you might want to look into using zathura; it might fit your use-case.